# SQL subtracting count(true) from count(false) value

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table named 'Vote' and there is a column named status. Status can have true or false values.

I want to find subtract result. Something like this

```
select (select count(*) from vote where status=true) - 
       (select (*) from vote where status=false)
```

the above sql is giving error: incorrect syntax near "*"

What would be the correct syntax to achieve the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select sum(
  (case when status='true' then 1 else -1 end)
)
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to write count in your second select

```
select count(*)
```

instead of

```
select (*)
```

So your query would become

```
select 
(select count(*) from vote where status = 'true') - (select count(*) from vote where status = 'false')
```

If datatype is bit then try this:

```
select 
    (select count(*) from vote where status = 1) - (select count(*) from vote where status = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select sum(
  (case when status='true' then 1 else 0 end)-
  (case when status='false' then 1 else 0 end)
)
from vote
```